# Java Write version info in zip file attribute

Tags: java, file, zip, version, fileversioninfo

I am exporting my data in form of zipping. I need to validate the version of my product, which version the file was exported. I have to validate the file version.

Is there any way in java that I can write/read the version of that file in File Detail as shown in below image?

[image]

```
try {
    Path inputFilePath = Paths.get(exportFilePath);
    Path outputFilePath = Paths.get(outputDirPath,
    String.format("%s.%s", inputFilePath.getFileName(), EXPORT_EXTENSION));
    fileZipper.zipIt(inputFilePath, outputFilePath);
    log.info("Zipping completed.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Got error whlie zipping file. ", e);
}
```

Also please suggest me the other way to achieve this.

Comment: From Java 7 on, it's easier to write custom file attributes. Take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/UserDefinedFileAttributeView.html).

Comment: What do you mean by validate the version? It looks like you're highlighting the archive bit in that image?

Comment: @DavidConrad I mean to say the version of a product or you can consider the product release version. This will be helpful to know which version of the zip is this.

Comment: @Mena Let me look into this than

Comment: How would you know the product release version from the zip? Your screenshot of file properties shows nothing like that.

Comment: @JamesZ yes, true. That's what my question is. I want to write the product release version in file details, so it will be visible under Details in windows system.

Comment: I think you need to delete this question and ask a new one, with clear explanation of what you're actually doing, and what you have tried so far.. This one is totally confusing and probably that's why there's no answers either.